# I want to store a column value of the first record and compare that value with the rest of the records

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

For instance, I have below data

> col1|col2|col3|col4
>
> aa|123|456|50
>
> bb|101|222|50
>
> cc|102|232|70
>
> dd|103|142|70
>
> ee|104|472|50

Here I want col4 value of the first record should be taken and compared with the rest of the records col4 and if it is mismatching, I want to capture it in another port. I would like to do it using Informatica not using Shell.

Desired Output

> col1|col2|col3|col4|col5
>
> aa|123|456|50|Matching
>
> bb|101|222|50|Matching
>
> cc|102|232|70|Not matching
>
> dd|103|142|70|Not matching
>
> ee|104|472|50|Matching

Please help me achieve this using Informatica not using Shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there you go. Create an expression and within:

1. Create a variable port that will just increase with every row, e.g. `v_counter = v_counter + 1`. Put it as the very last on the list of ports.
2. Create a variable port to hold your reference value, e.g. `v_ref_value = IIF(v_counter = 1, col4, v_ref_value)`. Make sure the **`v_counter`** is still the very last port on the list.
3. Add `col5` output port defined as `IIF(col4=v_ref_value, 'Matching', 'Not matching')`